# SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE GCM on one device but not the other

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am running a piece of code that registers to GCM.

on a LG L5 I am getting the SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE exception. However, on a Samsung galaxy S3, all seems to be working fine and I am not getting the exception.

Anybody encountered such an issue ?